# "Add Contact" activity.xml file is not correctly formatted in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I was watching this video to try and make a new activity that lets me add new contacts (the code appears right before 3:54): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjL4R-aiwPE.

After looking into the code and changing suggested fixes and even including some things that I left out, it still won't work correctly, whether it's the same exact code or not.
Can someone help me find the error?
Here's the code and an image of my output and the expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Add_Contact">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints=""/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etName"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etEmail"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/add_contact"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPhone" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Expected Output:

[image: Expectation]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Add_Contact">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPhone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etEmail" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/add_contact"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPhone" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I'll analyze the differences.

Comment: @André_Almeida Your welcome :)